How can I apply a scale transformation to a RigidBody?
I have a fixed SDFormat file, containing one link and representing a rigid body. How can I programmatically scale the resulting RigidBody? I'd prefer to be able to do this after plant finalization but doing this during the plant construction phase would already be helpful.
For a feature request, I'd ask for a RigidTransform but for scale. Is there something similar already in Drake?

Currently, there's no mechanism for scaling rigid bodies. When assigning geoemtries to them, you can scale the geometries w.r.t. contact extent or visual appearance.
But to scale the rigid body, you'd have to handle the mass properties appropriately.
Submitting a feature request and using that as a place to discuss would be a good idea.

I anticipate that all necessary API already exists, so we could probably prototype the helpful sugar in Anzu and go from there.

(The main MbP function to change the body would be SetSpatialInertiaInBodyFrame.  The main SG function to change the shape is ChangeShape.  Depending on what you want accomplish with scaling, there might be a few other properties you'd need to revisit / reset.)
